# How to create and call a promise in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, promise, google-cloud-firestore

I have been trying to make a call to the firestore with a function that I created with a `collection` variable.

```
var readFirestore = function(collection, doc){
    return promise = new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
      //If doc param is null Query collection
      if(doc == null || doc == "" || doc == undefined){
        var response = [];
        db.collection(collection).get()
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log('Error getting documents: ', err);
          reject(err);
      })
        .then((snapshot) => {
          snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            response.push(doc.id);
          });
          console.log(response);
          resolve(response);

        });

      }

    });
}
```

I call it via `appp.get`

```
app.get('/post', (req, res) => {
    readFirestore('fake',null).then(response => {
       res.json(response);
    }),(err) => {
      console.log(err);
      res.send(err);
  }

});
```

and it works but, when I tried to test the catch by giving it a wrong `collection` variable it refused to return the error.

Can anyone please help me fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: do you see the `Error getting documents` log?

Comment: @ManuelSpigolon Nope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You weren't passing the catch handler properly.

Change this:

```
app.get('/post', (req, res) => {
    readFirestore('fake',null).then(response => {
       res.json(response);
    }),(err) => {
      console.log(err);
      res.send(err);
  }

});
```

to this:

```
app.get('/post', (req, res) => {
    readFirestore('fake',null).then(response => {
       res.json(response);
    }, (err) => {
      console.log(err);
      res.send(err);
    });
});
```

Also, `readFirestore()` does not need to create its own promise (that's an anti-pattern).  It can just return the promise you already have.

Here's a restructured `readFirestore()` function:

```
function readFirestore(collection, doc) {
    //If doc param is null Query collection
    if (!doc) {
        return db.collection(collection).get().then((snapshot) => {
            const response = [];
            snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                response.push(doc.id);
            });
            return response;
        }).catch((err) => {
            // log the error, then rethrow
            // or, if you don't need to log the error here, then just get rid of the .catch()
            // here entirely as it doesn't change your logic flow, it's only here for logging
            console.log('Error getting documents: ', err);
            throw err;
        });
    } else {
        // it's unclear what you want returned here, but you need to return a promise
        // that resolves to something - you need to fill in this logic
        return Promise.resolve(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but how do I stop the anti-pattern in `readFirestore()`?

Comment: @UmarYusuf - I've added a restructured `readFirestore()` to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you call your function with a Collection that does not exist, it will not return an error but an empty array of [`QueryDocumentSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot)s. This is how the JavaScript SDK works.

You will get an error, if, for example, you try to fetch a Collection which is protected by a Security Rule.

As jfriend00 mentionned, you don't need to create your own promise since the [`get()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#get) method already returns a Promise. So you could adapt your function as follows:

```
var readFirestore = function(collection) {
    var response = [];
    return db
      .collection(collection)
      .get()
      .then((snapshot) => {
        snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          response.push(doc.id);
        });
        return response;
      })
  }
```

Comment: What of the error handling? `db.collection(collection).get()` has a `.catch() `that returns an error. I want to catch that and throw it and use in the `app.get`.

Comment: If an error is thrown in `readFirestore` you will get it into the calling function. You can give try by modifying your Firestore security rules in such a way reading is not allowed.